# Issue with Constructor of Struct nested in Class Template

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

I need to turn a linked list class for ints that I wrote into a class template. I'm having issues with the constructor and destructor for a struct nested in the List Class, called node.

Layout:

```
  template <typename T>
  class List
  {
    public:
      //Stuff that's not important to this question
    private:
      struct Node
      {
        Node(T value);              // constructor
        ~Node();                // destructor
        Node *next;             // pointer to the next Node
        T data;               // the actual data in the node
        static int nodes_alive; // count of nodes still allocated
      };
  };
```

Implementation:

```
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::Node::Node(T value)
{
  data = value;
  next = 0;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::Node::~Node()
{
   --nodes_alive;
}
```

Errors:

1. Expected ';' at end of declaration

   typename List::Node::Node(T value)
2. Expected an identifier or template ID after '::'

   typename List::Node::~Node()
3. Expected the class name after '~' to name a destructor

   typename List::Node::~Node()

Not really sure what's going on here. My implementation is in a separate file included at the bottom of the header file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot the `;` at the end of `class List`

Comment: although i forgot it when i copied it over, its correct in my source that is leading to errors. I'll fix the post though, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple: Get rid of the `typename` keyword. Since you're writing a constructor/destructor and there is no return type, it is not needed.

```
template <typename T>
List<T>::Node::Node(T value)
{
  data = value;
  next = 0;
}

template <typename T>
List<T>::Node::~Node()
{
   --nodes_alive;
}
```

Comment: Yup! That fixed my issue. Just to ensure I understand properly, I should only be using the typename keyword when I'm talking about a type that was created by a template?

Comment: Yes, that's about it. Since the return type is dependant on the template, it must be preceded by `typename` so the compiler knows it's a type.